# match two pattern in log file and output as table

Tags: awk

I need to match two patterns in a log file and need to get the output as a table if possible. The log file has several lines with the words I want to match, here is an example of the log file:

```
Seed for random set to: uuzTjCqMVRk=
    --out /home/ALL/ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA
    --max-shift False
    --min-shift False

p-value = 0.542

Seed for random set to: P2+shGCxj70=
    --out /home/ALL/BLD.CD14.MONO-EnhA
    --max-shift False
    --min-shift False

p-value = 0.737
```

I would like to get an output like this (tab delimited to export as text file):

```
Group   Pvalue
ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA   0.542
BLD.CD14.MONO-EnhA   0.737
```

I would like to do it in bash if it is possible

EDIT:

This is what I have tried:

```
grep 'out' file.log | awk '{print $0}' > file1.txt
grep 'p-value' file.log | awk '{print $0}' > file2.txt
paste -d"\t" file1.txt file2.txt > pval.txt
```

Comment: Can you paste what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero error-checking:

```
awk '/--out/ { sub(".*/","",$2);printf "%s\t",$2; } /p-value = / { print $3; }' < file.log
```

If a line has `--out`, prints the base name of the path followed by a tab. If a line has `p-value =`, prints the number and a newline.

`awk` is nice, in this case, because you can modify the lines you match. Thinking in terms of `grep`, you'd have to deploy additional tools (like `sed`) to get the parts you wanted, then reassemble them into a useful form. Your use of `grep` and `paste` is valiant, and with tweaking would work, at the cost of many more processes and deployed tools.

You could do this in one bigger block of awk pattern matching, which would be more bullet-proof. I'll leave as exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'[/ ]' -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN{print "Group","Pvalue"} (NR%7)==2{g=$NF} (NR%7)==6{print g, $NF}' file
Group   Pvalue
ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA      0.542
BLD.CD14.MONO-EnhA      0.737
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -F'[/ ]+' -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN{print "Group","Pvalue"} $2=="--out"{g=$NF} $1=="p-value"{print g, $NF}' file
Group   Pvalue
ADRL.GLND.FET-EnhA      0.542
BLD.CD14.MONO-EnhA      0.737
```